# How to get input value before WKWebView changes with Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, wkwebview

I have a basic iOS app developed in Swift. I'm using a `WkWebView` to load my website and require to get an inputs value before the page is changed so that I can save it into `NSUserDefaults`.

I can use the following to simply populate the inputs value:

```
 webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('myInput').value = 'Test';") { (result, error) in
 if error != nil {
     print(result)
 }
```

Although how can I get the value of an input from a WKWebView?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a java script to capture the changes in webview and send the data asynchronously to wkconfiguration delegate to collect the data.

Adding JS to wkwebkit means lot of control, even you can add jquery as well.

This is just a hint where you can create your ideas.

-

```
(void) addJSScriptToWebConfig
{
    NSString *JS = ...;
    WKWebViewConfiguration *webViewConfig = [[SBWKWebViewConfiguration sharedInstance] configuration];
    WKUserScript *script3 = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:JS injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
    [webViewConfig.userContentController addUserScript:script3];

    [webViewConfig.userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self
                                                           name:@"callbackFunc"];
```

Comment: How is that even possible? How can Javascript from a webpage communicate with Swift in an iOS app...? It would be great if you could provide a basic example on how to achieve this.

Comment: it is not you web page's JS, it the JS file/asset added in ios app and linked to wkwebconfiguration .. update answer for the same